# How to render a component with props derivative from NextJS router

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to render a component that uses a dynamic router path prop. I want `mysite.com/something` to load the component with the `something` prop. If the route is `mysite.com/somethingelse`, I want to load the component with the `somethingelse` prop. Here's my code:

`page.js`:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import List from "./List";

function DefaultPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(router.query.category); // Works correctly
  return (
    <div>
      <List category={router.query.category} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default DefaultPage;
```

The component, `list.js`:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props.category); // This is where I'm confused
  }

  static defaultProps = { category: "default" };

  render() {
    return <p>Hello</p>;
  }
}

export default List;
```

The problem is, `this.props.category` always returns as `default` (my default prop), unless I recompile. It works perfectly after a fresh compile, but then breaks after every subsequent refresh in the browser.

I can visually see the router query returning the *correct* value in the log, but the component is rendering *before* everything else, thus returning a default value. Is there a way I can stop the List component from rendering before its own props are specified? Or is there a better way of doing this all together? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to see the value update in the `List`'s `componentDidMount`. `useRouter` values will update after the first mount.

Comment: Unfortunately `this.props.category` is still "default" in `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this in the DefaultPage component:

```
if(router.query.category === 'something') {
 return <ListComponent/>
}

if(router.query.category === 'somethingElse') {
 return <SomethingElseComponent/>
}
```

If you don't want to use two separate components, you could pass the prop to useEffect so it can re-render the component when that prop changes https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: I just tried with the useEffect hook. Loading the component with useEffect as opposed to componentDidMount does exactly the same thing, except it returns a blank object instead. Just like the initial problem I was having, it works after compiling, then following every refresh/recompile, it returns a blank object.